# How do you read a Python Traceback error?

Tags: python

I have run some Python code in Windows 10 and gotten the Traceback error below. Does it mean the string that is supposed to be an int occurs in line `347` of `/DeOldify/deoldify/filters.py` or line `1943` of `/lib/site-packages/PIL/Image.py`?

For context, below the traceback error, I've also included the steps that lead to this error (I attempted to colorize a black and white film clip based on the DeOldify Colab https://colab.research.google.com/github/jantic/DeOldify/blob/master/VideoColorizerColab.ipynb but only succeeded at colorizing the first frame as a .jpeg) and the full terminal output.

EDIT: Thanks to @Daweo's response, I discovered the problem was with the arguments I entered into the terminal as indicated by `"<stdin>", line 1`. The correct command should have been:
`video_path = colorizer.colorize_from_file_name(file_name='my_video.mp4', render_factor=render_factor)`
Also, the code for colorizing a photograph is from https://colab.research.google.com/github/jantic/DeOldify/blob/master/ImageColorizerColab.ipynb

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):----------------------------| 0.00% [0/1378 00:00<00:00]
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\python-virtual-environments\DeOldify\deoldify\visualize.py", line 347, in colorize_from_file_name
        return self._colorize_from_path(
  File "C:\python-virtual-environments\DeOldify\deoldify\visualize.py", line 359, in _colorize_from_path
        self._colorize_raw_frames(
  File "C:\python-virtual-environments\DeOldify\deoldify\visualize.py", line 273, in _colorize_raw_frames
        color_image = self.vis.get_transformed_image(
  File "C:\python-virtual-environments\DeOldify\deoldify\visualize.py", line 178, in get_transformed_image
        filtered_image = self.filter.filter(
  File "C:\python-virtual-environments\DeOldify\deoldify\filters.py", line 121, in filter
        filtered_image = filter.filter(orig_image, filtered_image, render_factor, post_process)
  File "C:\python-virtual-environments\DeOldify\deoldify\filters.py", line 83, in filter
        model_image = self._model_process(orig=filtered_image, sz=render_sz)
  File "C:\python-virtual-environments\DeOldify\deoldify\filters.py", line 45, in _model_process
        model_image = self._get_model_ready_image(orig, sz)
  File "C:\python-virtual-environments\DeOldify\deoldify\filters.py", line 40, in _get_model_ready_image
        result = self._scale_to_square(orig, sz)
  File "C:\python-virtual-environments\DeOldify\deoldify\filters.py", line 37, in _scale_to_square
        return orig.resize(targ_sz, resample=PIL.Image.BILINEAR)
  File "C:\python-virtual-environments\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1943, in resize
        return self._new(self.im.resize(size, resample, box))
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Steps:

-Extracted 5 seconds of a black and white film as a UYVY .mp4 file called `my_video.mp4` with AviSynth and WinFF

-Added `C:\ffmpeg\bin\` to Path

-Installed Microsoft C++ Build Tools

-Setup a virtual Python environment

-`pip install numpy scipy matplotlib ipython`

-`git clone https://github.com/jantic/DeOldify.git DeOldify`

-`cd DeOldify`

-`pip install torch`

-`pip install -r colab_requirements.txt`

-`mkdir models`

-Downloaded `https://data.deepai.org/deoldify/ColorizeVideo_gen.pth` to `./models/ColorizeVideo_gen.pth`

and `https://data.deepai.org/deoldify/ColorizeArtistic_gen.pth` to `./models/ColorizeArtistic_gen.pth`

-Python commands:

```
from deoldify import device
from deoldify.device_id import DeviceId
#device.set(device=DeviceId.GPU0)
device.set(device=DeviceId.CPU)
import torch
import fastai
from deoldify.visualize import *
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning, message=".*?Your .*? set is empty.*?")
```

-Relocated the video file `my_video.mp4` to `./DeOldify/video/source/my_video.mp4`

```
colorizer = get_video_colorizer()
source_url = 'my_video.mp4'
render_factor = 21
watermarked = True

video_path = colorizer.colorize_from_file_name(source_url, 'video.mp4', render_factor)
```

The result is the creation of a directory with the black and white frames `./DeOldify/video/bwframes/my_video/`. However, the color frames folder `./DeOldify/video/colorframes/my_video/` is empty.

-Just to see if it would work; took the first black and white frame `00001.jpg` and placed it in `./DeOldify/` then ran the following code:

```
colorizer = get_image_colorizer(artistic=True)
source_url = '00001.jpg'
render_factor = 35

image_path = colorizer.plot_transformed_image(path=source_url, render_factor=render_factor, compare=True)
```

A colorized version of the first frame is created as `./DeOldify/result_images/00001.jpg`

The full output for the video command with error:

```
>>> video_path = colorizer.colorize_from_file_name(source_url, 'video.mp4', render_factor)
ffmpeg version N-92462-g529debc987 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20181017
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 23.101 / 56. 23.101
  libavcodec     58. 39.100 / 58. 39.100
  libavformat    58. 22.100 / 58. 22.100
  libavdevice    58.  6.100 / 58.  6.100
  libavfilter     7. 44.100 /  7. 44.100
  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video\source\my_video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.42.101
  Duration: 00:00:27.59, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2636 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x576, 2500 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 12800 tbn, 100 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Please use -q:a or -q:v, -qscale is ambiguous
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    [swscaler @ 0000025261e16f80] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to 'video\bwframes\my_video\%5d.jpg':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.22.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 720x576, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.39.100 mjpeg
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame= 1378 fps=499 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:27.56 bitrate=N/A speed=9.99x
video:75662kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Traceback (most recent call last):----------------------------| 0.00% [0/1378 00:00<00:00]
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\python-virtual-environments\DeOldify\deoldify\visualize.py", line 347, in colorize_from_file_name
    return self._colorize_from_path(
  File "C:\python-virtual-environments\DeOldify\deoldify\visualize.py", line 359, in _colorize_from_path
    self._colorize_raw_frames(
  File "C:\python-virtual-environments\DeOldify\deoldify\visualize.py", line 273, in _colorize_raw_frames
    color_image = self.vis.get_transformed_image(
  File "C:\python-virtual-environments\DeOldify\deoldify\visualize.py", line 178, in get_transformed_image
    filtered_image = self.filter.filter(
  File "C:\python-virtual-environments\DeOldify\deoldify\filters.py", line 121, in filter
    filtered_image = filter.filter(orig_image, filtered_image, render_factor, post_process)
  File "C:\python-virtual-environments\DeOldify\deoldify\filters.py", line 83, in filter
    model_image = self._model_process(orig=filtered_image, sz=render_sz)
  File "C:\python-virtual-environments\DeOldify\deoldify\filters.py", line 45, in _model_process
    model_image = self._get_model_ready_image(orig, sz)
  File "C:\python-virtual-environments\DeOldify\deoldify\filters.py", line 40, in _get_model_ready_image
    result = self._scale_to_square(orig, sz)
  File "C:\python-virtual-environments\DeOldify\deoldify\filters.py", line 37, in _scale_to_square
    return orig.resize(targ_sz, resample=PIL.Image.BILINEAR)
  File "C:\python-virtual-environments\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1943, in resize
    return self._new(self.im.resize(size, resample, box))
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Comment: Thank you @Daweo. The example you provided as well as the web tutorial were very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Does it mean the string that is supposed to be an int occurs in line 347 of /DeOldify/deoldify/filters.py or line 1943 of /lib/site-packages/PIL/Image.py*

This imply something in `filters.py` is responsbile for such usage of something from `Image.py` that raised `TypeError`.

Consider simple example let `zerodiv.py` content be:

```
def f():
    return 1/0
def g():
    return f()
def h():
    return g()
print(h())
```

then

```
python zerodiv.py
```

will give following output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zerodiv.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(h())
  File "zerodiv.py", line 6, in h
    return g()
  File "zerodiv.py", line 4, in g
    return f()
  File "zerodiv.py", line 2, in f
    return 1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

So as you can see it is course of actions which lead to Error. If you want to know more about python traceback I suggest reading [realpython.com tutorial - Understanding the Python Traceback](https://realpython.com/python-traceback/).